# How to get info about position element in the table?

Tags: postgresql

I have query:

```
Select * from mytable order by 'date'
```

And result:

```
   date    | item_id | user_id | some_data
------------------------------------------
2015-01-01 |       1 |       1 | null
2015-01-01 |       1 |       1 | null
2015-01-02 |       1 |       1 | null
2015-01-03 |       1 |       1 | null
2015-01-03 |       1 |       2 | null
2015-01-04 |       1 |       1 | null
2015-01-05 |       1 |       2 | null
```

And I want to get position of first row where user_id = 2. In this example it be 5. How to do it?

Comment: `order by 'date'` is invalid SQL. `'date'` is a character literal, not a column name

Comment: Take a look at `row_number()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select pos_overall
from (
  select user_id, 
         row_number() over (order by "date") as pos_overall,
         row_number() over (partition by user_id order by "date") as user_pos
  from mytable
) t
where user_id = 2
  and user_pos = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the row_number() function to number the rows in order of date, user_id and then select the minimum value:

```
select min(rn) 
from (
  select 
    user_id, row_number() over (order by date, user_id) as rn 
  from mytable 
) x
where user_id = 2;
```

If the item_id can change you might want to include that in the order by clause for the row_number function in the derived table.